# Can I create a flat table report in Adobe Analytics?

Tags: reporting, adobe-analytics

Is it possible in Adobe Analytics to build a simple flat table report with, for example, three columns: `Device, First Touch Channel, Visits`.

I don't want to manually drag and drop the second dimensions into each of the first dimension instances. It is very annoying if I have a lot of values and it is very painful to read a nested table.